# fill out NA value with the same code char in the same group

Tags: python, pandas, na, autofill

I have this dataset. I would like to fill out NA value with the same code char in the same group.

in this example the first NA will be S, and the second one will be F

Thank you,

```
df = {'Key': ['111*1', '111*2','111*3', '222*1','222*2', '333*1','333*2', '333*3','333*4', '444*1'],
        'code': ['S', 'S','NA', 'M','M', 'F','F', 'F','NA', 'C']}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df[['Keya', 'Keyb']] = df['Key'].str.split('\\*', expand=True, regex=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
s = df['code'].replace('NA', np.nan)

df['code'] = s.fillna(s.groupby(df['Key'].str.extract('([^*]+)*', expand=False))
                       .transform('first')
                     )
```

If you already have Keya:

```
s = df['code'].replace('NA', np.nan)

df['code'] = s.fillna(s.groupby(df['Keya']).transform('first'))
```

Output:

```
     Key code
0  111*1    S
1  111*2    S
2  111*3    S
3  222*1    M
4  222*2    M
5  333*1    F
6  333*2    F
7  333*3    F
8  333*4    F
9  444*1    C
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have a question please. Can I split the data into train 80% and test 20%. However, I do not want to split the same group keys. I want to be each group either in train or test.

Comment: This is certainly possible, but should be the focus of a separate question